# Did iOS 17.4 break the associated domains AutoFill for FaceID?

Tags: ios, autofill, face-id, password-manager, password-autofill

I’m looking to see if anybody else has noticed that iOS 17.4 seems to have broken password autofill for associated domains.

Meaning if I open my app to the login page (web view) it recognizes the associated domains and the password in my keychain.

If I tap on my username my keychain is unlocked with biometrics (FaceID) and I’m returned to the page, but the user name and password field is not filed in.
This just started happening in iOS 17.4 (17.3.1 works fine for example).

I have learned that this works properly for TouchID devices or if you go into settings --> Face ID & Passcodes --> Password AutoFill (toggle off) the password manager works as expected.

Interestingly, if you choose the  icon on the right side of the keyboard and then choose your credentials you get a blank page until you tap in a text field then the username and password show up.

I have filled out a bug report with Apple, but in the mean time I was curious if anybody else has seen this or have a solution.

Comment: iOS 17.4 definitely broke a couple of things at least here in EU, where they rolled out browser engines. For me one-time-passcode AutoFill stopped working in in-app WKWebView, however it does work on same page in Safari.